# How to create a blur (fall-off) in a material using node?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, displacement, blur

I am trying to make a procedural displacement texture using a gradual fall off.Lets say we have created the following texture:
L[image]

Now I want to give a fall off(or blur the texture) to the give texture like this:
[image]
I checked some tutorials and was not able to find a proper ssolution. Most of the tutorial uses a noise texture, for the texture which is working fine, but for displacement it is creating spikes in the object.
I was not able to find a mathematical fuction for bluring a vector image which can be used in blender.
So can someone suggest me a way/or a mathematical fuction to blur(give fall off) a texture using the material nodes.

Comment: As far as I know, that's not possible because of how the renderer works : basically, a pixel don't know the state of neighbours pixels when it is rendered, so it can't be blured with them.

Comment: Yes i was also thinking the same thing, but i thought that someone on internet might have some suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Are you doing displacement in material nodes, or in modifiers?